# On the equivalence of some Hölder semi norms

Tags: real-analysis

I am perplexed by the section on page 55 of ​this [lecture note](https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf). There he defines this semi-norm $$[D^2u]^*_{\alpha;B1}:=\sup_{B_{\rho}(x_0)\subset B_1}\rho^{2+\alpha}[D^2u]_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_{\rho/2}(x_0))}$$
where the bracket $[\cdot]$ on the RHS is the usual Hölder norm. Attempting to show that this semi-norm is equivalent to that replacing $\rho/2$ on the RHS by $\rho/4$, the author covers $B_{\rho/2}(x_0)$ by $B_{\rho/8}(z_i)$, and inferring that

<s>**Question 1:** Why do $(\frac{\rho}{2})^{2+\alpha}$ appear on the LHS of $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(\frac{\rho}{2})^{2+\alpha}[D^2u]_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_{\rho/8}(z_j))}\leq \sup_{B_{\rho}(x_0)\subset B_1} \rho^{2+\alpha}[D^2u]_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_{\rho/4}(x_0))}}$ instead of $\rho^{2+\alpha}$?</s>
**Edit:** This is solved.

**Question 2:** The author claims *Hölder semi-norms are sub-additive with respect to
unions of convex sets* so that $$\rho^{2+\alpha}[D^2u]_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_{\rho/2}(x_0))}\leq C\rho^{2+\alpha}\sum^N_{j=1}[D^2u]_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_{\rho/8}(z_j))}$$ but since so far I have not obtained such a claim myself, I doubt if this inequality is even true.

**Question 3** Is this semi-norm equivalent to that $$[u]^*_{2,\alpha;B1}:=\sup_{x,y\in \Omega} d_{x,y}^{2+\alpha}\frac{\vert D^2u(y)-D^2(x)\vert}{\vert y-x\vert^\alpha}$$
introduced in Gilbarg/Trudinger (4.17)?
Here $d_{x,y}$ := the closer distance of $x$ or $y$ to the boundary $\partial \Omega$.

**My attemp:** I think the answer is affirmative (at least for $B_1$). First
$$[D^2u]^*_{\alpha;B_1}\leq [u]^*_{2,\alpha;B_1}$$ follows from the definitions. On the other hand we can assume $\vert x-y \vert \geq  \frac{1}{2}d_{x,y}$ and let $x_j$ lie on the segment $\overline{x0}$ with successive distance $r_j = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^jd_{x,y}$ from $x$, so that each ball $x_{j-1}\in B_{r_j}(x_j)$ and similarly for $y_j$. $$\vert D^2u(x)-D^2u(y)\vert \leq \sum^{N-1}_{i=1}\vert D^2u(x_i)-D^2u(x_{i-1})\vert + \sum^{N-1}_{i=1}\vert D^2u(x_i)-D^2u(x_{i-1})\vert + \vert D^2u(x_N)-D^2u(y_N) \vert$$ where $N$ is chosen so that $\vert x_N - y_N\vert \leq d_{x,y}$. Observe that $$\vert D^2 u(x_i) - D^2u(u_{i-1})\vert \leq 2^\alpha r^{-2}_i[D^2u]^*_{\alpha;B_1}$$
This allows us to conclude $$\vert D^2u(x)-D^2u(y)\vert \leq \frac{C}{d^2_{x,y}}[D^2u]^*_{\alpha;B_1}$$ and hence $[u]^*_{2,\alpha;B_1}\leq C[D^2u]^*_{\alpha;B1}$. For general $\Omega$ (probably unbounded) I am not sure if this equivalence still holds.

Thank you for your patience to read through these question.

Comment: For question 1, notice that the centers of the balls in the seminorms are not the same.